# Cannot convert expression type of generic where Template is MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types

I have some kind of MonoBehaviour pool:

```
public class MonoPool<T> where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<T> PrefabPool { get; }

    public MonoPool() {
        PrefabPool = new List<T>();
    }

    public void AddObject(T prefab)
    {
        PrefabPool.Add(prefab);
    }
}
```

And I want that all generators of ILevelGenerator interface returns MonoPool on Create()

```
public interface ILevelGenerator
{
    public MonoPool<MonoBehaviour> Create();
    public void Update();
    public void SetMode(int mode);
}
```

For example I have a BuildingsGenerator and it implements this ILevelGenerator

```
public class BuildingsGenerator : ILevelGenerator
{
    private readonly MonoPool<ModularBuilding> _buildingsPool;

    public BuildingsGenerator() {
        _buildingsPool = new MonoPool<ModularBuilding>();
    }
    
    public MonoPool<MonoBehaviour> Create()
    {
        //Logic...
        //Logic...

        return _buildingsPool;
    }
}
```

BuildingsGenerator implement MonoPool as MonoPool there ModularBuilding is MonoBeh

```
public class ModularBuilding : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private BuildingFloor _groundFloorElement;
    [SerializeField] private BuildingFloor _middleFloorElement;
    [SerializeField] private BuildingFloor _roofFloorElement;
    
    public void AssembleBuilding(ushort requiredFloors)
    {
        //Logic
    }
}
```

But when I want to return this generic list the compiler throws the following error:

> Cannot convert expression type 'Pools.MonoPool<Actors.Buildings.ModularBuilding>' to return type 'Pools.MonoPool<UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour>'

Why? How? I'we made MonoPool but i can't return it...

Comment: You are trying to assign one type to another and this is not a valid option. It is the same as something like `string val = new System.Timer();`. What do you want to get as a result of such strange manipulations?

Comment: @Morion A Level Generator in unity returning a pool of objects it created.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, solution founded: I've changed ILevelGenerator to this:

```
public interface ILevelGenerator<T> where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MonoPool<T> Create();
    public void Update();
    public void SetMode(int mode);
}
```

And chaged ILevelGenerator inheretor to this:

```
public class BuildingsGenerator : ILevelGenerator<ModularBuilding>
{
    private readonly MonoPool<ModularBuilding> _buildingsPool;

    public BuildingsGenerator() {
        _buildingsPool = new MonoPool<ModularBuilding>();
    }
    
    public MonoPool<ModularBuilding> Create()
    {
        //Logic...
        //Logic...

        return _buildingsPool;
    }
}
```

And chenged declaration as well

```
    private readonly ILevelGenerator<ModularBuilding> _buildingsGenerator;
    private readonly ILevelGenerator<Cloud> _cloudsGenerator;
```

So now it works